# Testing JSTL String value?

Tags: string, jsf, testing, jstl

I'm working with JSF and JSTL, the code above doesn't work!

```
<ui:repeat var="reponse" value="#{gPost.reponses}">                                             UserLogin : #{reponse.utilisateur.login}
    <c:if test="${reponse.utilisateur.login eq 'X'}">
        Utilisateur equivalent X
    </c:if>
</ui:repeat>
```

This code iterate, i have two element to be iterated, the output is this :

```
UserLogin : Y
UserLogin : X
```

It must be :

```
UserLogin : Y
UserLogin : X
Utilisateur equivalent X
```

The tag `<c:if test="${reponse.utilisateur.login eq 'X'}">` is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

JSTL tags like `<c:if>` runs during view build time, while JSF components like `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time. So, with your code given so far, the `#{reponse}` is **not** available while JSTL is running, because `<ui:repeat>` hasn't run. You need a normal JSF component with `rendered` attribute instead.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{reponse.utilisateur.login eq 'X'}">
    Utilisateur equivalent X
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)